# Generating thumbnails - unwanted black background

Tags: php, gd

I use this script to resize picture from original size to thumbnail:

```
<?php

function resize($newWidth, $originalFile, $targetFile) {

$info = getimagesize($originalFile);

$mime = $info['mime'];

switch ($mime) {
        case 'image/jpeg':
                $image_create_func = 'imagecreatefromjpeg';
                $image_save_func = 'imagejpeg';
                $new_image_ext = 'jpg';
                break;

        case 'image/png':
                $image_create_func = 'imagecreatefrompng';
                $image_save_func = 'imagepng';
                $new_image_ext = 'png';
                break;

        case 'image/gif':
                $image_create_func = 'imagecreatefromgif';
                $image_save_func = 'imagegif';
                $new_image_ext = 'gif';
                break;

        default: 
                throw Exception('Unknown image type.');
}


$img = $image_create_func($targetFile,100);
$width = $info[0];
$height = $info[1];
$newHeight = ($height / $width) * $newWidth;
$tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
imagecopyresampled($tmp, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);

if (file_exists($targetFile)) {
        unlink($targetFile);
}

$image_save_func($tmp, $targetFile);

echo "<img src='$targetFile'>";

}

?>
```

...and

```
<?php

echo "<pre>"; var_dump(gd_info()); echo "</pre>";

?>
```

returns:

```
array(12) {
["GD Version"]=>
string(26) "bundled (2.1.0 compatible)"
["FreeType Support"]=>
bool(true)
["FreeType Linkage"]=>
string(13) "with freetype"
["T1Lib Support"]=>
bool(true)
["GIF Read Support"]=>
bool(true)
["GIF Create Support"]=>
bool(true)
["JPEG Support"]=>
bool(true)
["PNG Support"]=>
bool(true)
["WBMP Support"]=>
bool(true)
["XPM Support"]=>
bool(true)
["XBM Support"]=>
bool(true)
["JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support"]=>
bool(false)
}
```

...but it generates thumbs with black backgrounds. No errors or warnings are displayed. Display errors is set to "on". All images I'm testing with now are .jpg formats. Please, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're never actually reading in the image data from `$originalFile`.

Comment: Thanks, you mean, I have to change `$img = $image_create_func($targetFile,100);` to `$img = $image_create_func($originalFile,100);` ? I tried, but still black backgrounds...

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your php file and try again:

`ini_set("gd.jpeg_ignore_warning", 1);`

I had this problem too. The gd library silently fails at one point (file-encoding). If you tell it to ignore these silent errors it should work.

**EDIT:**

Ok like **Rob Starling** pointed out, you try to read the targetfile instead of your *original*. If you correct this and still have black images, try my solution again :D

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but it has no effect in my case. Still black backgrounds:-(

Comment: I still don't understand, please, can you explain it more? Where, which line, I have to read `$originalFile`?